# Javascript get parent of item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to get the parent of a specific (referenced) object in an array.
Example:

```
var data = [
    {
        key: "value1"
        children: [
            {
                key: "value2"
            },
            {
                key: "value3"
                children: [
                    {
                        key: "value3a"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "value3b"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "value4"
    }
];
```

When some stuff happens, I get the following:

```
var clicked = {
    key: "value3a"
}
```

In this case I know that `value3a` has been clicked, and it's databound with the `data` variable.

The question is, how do I easily get the parent of `clicked`? It should return the whole children-array of `value3` which I want:

```
[
    {
        key: "value3a"
    },
    {
        key: "value3b"
    }
]
```

Note: currently I am using UnderscoreJS to find the object of my array. So maybe UnderscoreJS could help?

Comment: Take a look on this example that demonstrates tree with click: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691917/how-do-display-a-collapsible-tree-in-angularjs-bootstrap/19692791#19692791

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript objects: get parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980763/javascript-objects-get-parent)

Comment: Have a look into the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154070/4373895

Answer (score 0):

Just create a child-parent map so that you can look up what you need:

```
var map = {};
function recurse(arr, parent) {
    if (!arr) return;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { // use underscore here if you find it simpler
        map[arr[i].key] = parent;
        recurse(arr[i].children, arr[i]);
    }
}
recurse(data, {key:"root", children:data});
```

Now, in your event handler you can trivially use that map to look up your siblings:

```
map[clicked.key].children
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive reduce function.

```
// Given
var data = [
    {
        key: "value1",
        children: [
            {
                key: "value2"
            },
            {
                key: "value3",
                children: [
                    {
                        key: "value3a"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "value3b"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "value4"
    }
];
var clicked = {
    key: "value3a"
};
```

We can define a recursive reduce function, and give it the parent
as the context.

```
var rec_reduce = function(memo, obj) {
    if(obj.key == clicked.key) {
        return this || memo;
    }
    return _.reduce(obj.children, rec_reduce, memo, obj.children) || memo;
};

// Now we can lookup the key in clicked with one line
_.reduce(data, rec_reduce, null, data);

// Returns [{key: "value3a"}, {key: "value3b"}]
```

Or, if you want to leverage underscore to make a map as suggested in the first answer, that is even simpler:

```
var map = {};
var rec_map = function(obj, i, parent) {
    map[obj.key] = parent;
    _.each(obj.children, rec_map);
};
_.each(data, rec_map);

// Now getting the parent list is just a look up in the map
map[clicked.key]

// Returns [{key: "value3a"}, {key: "value3b"}]
```